# STL list access to next-to-last element

Tags: c++, list, stl

How do I get an iterator to the next-to-last element in a STL list without creating a temporary and modifying the list?
Is it possible to just say: `--(--mylist.end())`? Or would this change the `end` iterator of the list due to the prefix decrement?

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322104/how-portable-is-end-iterator-decrement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that in general, `--mylist.end()` is not guaranteed to compile for every container.

For example, if you use a `std::vector` or `std::array` in release mode, `mylist.end()` is probably a raw pointer, and you cannot decrement a pointer returned by value from a function.

A generic solution to this problem in C++11 is `std::prev(std::prev(mylist.end()))`, after checking that the list is long enough, of course. You need to `#include <iterator>` for this.

Comment: Interesting. But why can't i decrement a pointer returned by value. That's exactly why it doesn't change the `end` iterator itself, due to returning by value

Comment: Because a call to a function that returns by value is an rvalue, but the `--` operator for scalars (such as ints or raw pointers) requires an lvalue. Just try `--new T();` and you will get a compiler error saying "lvalue required as decrement operand" or something like that. On the other hand, it is perfectly fine to call operator `--` on a temporary object, as long as it is implemented as a member function. In practice, it won't work for *postfix* `--`, because that one is usually implemented as a free function (in terms of prefix `--`, to avoid code duplication), not as a member function.

Comment: Can you replace "std::prev(std::prev(mylist.end()))"  with just "end()-2" for containers with bidirectional iterators like vector ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) and a reverse_iterator:

```
SomeContainerType::reverse_iterator it = myList.rbegin();
std::advance(it, 1); // next to last element
```

This works even if the iterator type in question does not support `operator+`.

Comment: Or for that matter a forward iterator: `auto it = myList.end(); std::advance(it, -2);`.

Answer (score 2):

if okay with a `reverse_iterator`, then: `some_list.rbegin() + 1;`

Comment: Assuming `some_list` is a `std::list` the iterator will not support `operator+`

Comment: std::list supports bidirectional iterators; as Nim says, just call method  rbegin() and take the following elements with operator++