# Increment on unique_ptr causes unexpected behaviour of user-defined operator!=

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

This is a very specific issue and is a bit long to explain, so please bear with me as I try to summarize this as best I can.

I create 2 user types, the first is used inside the second :

```
struct mySubType {
    int val;
    mySubType () {}
    mySubType ( int _val) : val(_val){}
    bool operator!=(const mySubType& rhs) const { return val != rhs.val; }
};

struct myType {
    mySubType start;
    mySubType stop;
    myType () {}
    myType (mySubType _start, mySubType _stop) : start(_start), stop(_stop) {}
};
```

In `main()`, I create a `vector` of `unique_ptr` to `myType` and fill it as such :

```
vector<unique_ptr<myType>> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    v.push_back( unique_ptr<myType>(new myType( mySubType(i), mySubType(i+1))) );
```

So the `val` of `start` and `stop` for each element is as follows :

```
start:0 stop:1
start:1 stop:2
start:2 stop:3
start:3 stop:4
start:4 stop:5
start:5 stop:6
start:6 stop:7
start:7 stop:8
start:8 stop:9
start:9 stop:10
```

`start` should always be the same as previous `stop` (this is the case in this example). To check this, I tried the following :

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != --v.end(); )
{
    if ((*it)->stop != (*(++it))->start)
        cout << "1";
}
```

To my surprise, the output was : `111111111`, all different when they should be all equal.

I tried a few other things to try and understand the source of the error. I replaced the inside of the loop with

```
mySubType stop = (*it)->stop;
mySubType next_start = (*(++it))->start;
if (stop != next_start)
    cout << "2";
```

and then

```
if ((*it)->stop.val != (*(++it))->start.val)
    cout << "3";
```

Neither of those printed anything (all tests were correctly solved as equal).

This only happens when using `unique_ptr` (`vector<myType>` does not have the same issue). I also tried using post-increment but I get the exact same result.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens ?

I know there are a lot of ways to work around this issue (the 2 above for example). What I'm interested in is *why* this behaviour happens.

Comment: `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != --v.end(); )` - what should this even mean?

Comment: ```((*it)->stop != (*(++it))->start)``` are you sure that part to the left of ```!=``` will be evaluated before the part to the right of ```!=``` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: See also: [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) and [`std::adjacent_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference)

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I see, but then why does adding ```.val``` change anything ? Pure coincidence ?

Comment: @DenisSheremet iterate until element before last. The increment happens inside the loop, hence why there is no ++it. Is it not a valid syntax ?

Comment: Well, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322104/how-portable-is-end-iterator-decrement) and it looks contradictory, on the one hand it seems to be common technique for stl containers, on the other hand, it's not guaranteed to be implemented in a such way for all kinds of iterators. I'd suggest `std::next` here to avoud ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression in the if statement

```
    if ((*it)->stop != (*(++it))->start)
```

has undefined behavior.

It seems you mean the following loop

```
#include <iterator>

// ...

for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it )
{
    auto next = std::next( it );
    if ( next != v.end() && (*it)->stop != (*( next ))->start)
        std::cout << "1";
}
```

Instead of the for loop you could use the standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct mySubType {
    int val;
    mySubType () {}
    mySubType ( int _val) : val(_val){}
    bool operator!=(const mySubType& rhs) const { return val != rhs.val; }
};

struct myType {
    mySubType start;
    mySubType stop;
    myType () {}
    myType (mySubType _start, mySubType _stop) : start(_start), stop(_stop) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myType>> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.push_back( std::unique_ptr<myType>(new myType( mySubType(i), mySubType(i+1))) );

    auto it = std::adjacent_find( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
                                 []( const auto &left, const auto &right )
                                 {
                                     return left->stop != right->start;
                                 } );

    if ( it != std::end( v ) ) std::cout << "there is an error\n";
    else std::cout << "The sequence is correct\n";
}
```

The program output is

```
The sequence is correct
```

Comment: I agree that the comparison invokes undefined behavior since the evaluation order is unspecified. But I do not see, per se, a problem with the incrementing in the loop. The iterator is incremented during the comparison and hence exactly once in the loop.

Comment: @n314159 I took into account that within the body of the loop there is undefined behavior,:)

Comment: In this case, ```if ((*it)->stop.val != (*(++it))->start.val)``` has undefined behaviour too, right ? Does it work out of pure chance, then ?

Comment: @JeremyMaille I am sorry. I have not understood your question. I showed how the loop can be changed or substituted for the standard algorithm std::adjacent_find.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, however I did write "I know there are a lot of ways to work around this issue (the 2 above for example). What I'm interested in is _why_ this behaviour happens."
So my question is : why does `if ((*it)->stop != (*(++it))->start)` yield wrong results but `if ((*it)->stop.val != (*(++it))->start.val)` yields the right results.

Comment: @JeremyMaille It depends on the object code generated by the compiler. In the first case there is used a function order of evaluation of its arguments is unspecified.