# Is incrementing/decrementing or adding an integer value to a pointer that is not pointing to an element in a sequence Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic

I know that pointers (to array element) and iterators can be incremented/decremented to walk a sequence of elements and can jump back-and-for elements in the sequence.

But what will happen if I increment a pointer to a single object or add to it an integer value? is it undefined behavior or it is OK but we cannot access that memory?

```
int x = 551;
int* p = &x;
++p;
--p;
std::cout << *p << '\n';
```

Because I've already read that we should not increment/decrement a pointer that doesn't point to an element in a sequence or an array for example.

So can someone explain what will happen and whether my example is OK (de-referencing pointer p)? Thank you!

Comment: This is a very good question, because compiler writers are getting ever more aggressive at exploiting undefined behavior rules and making code have totally unpredictable consequences when you accidentally trip over a corner case.

Comment: That's not a great duplicate. It doesn't even touch on the subtraction case, which could reasonably have been (but actually isn't) handled differently.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, that's reasonable. This is slightly more general than the other. I'll swing the target direction, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

when pointer arithmetic applies to a pointer that points to an object, the pointer is considered to point to an array of that object type with only one element, as said in the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#footnote-86).

> An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose

In you example, the pointer `p` as if it point to `int arr[1] = {551}`
So, the corresponding operation is similar to apply to a pointer that point to the `arr`. That means, `++p` will make `p` point to the element arr[1] (hypothetical), and `--p` will make `p` point to the first element arr[0] again. So, in the last, de-referenceing pointer `p` is OK and does not result in any UB.

Answer (score -5):

#### Summary

Your program is *not* well-defined, even before getting to the dereference.

- **You may increment `p` once**, resulting in **a one-past-the-end pointer**.
- However, **you may not decrement a one-past-the-end pointer**.

  - [Some iterator types permit such an operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5322104/4386278), but this is not one of them (even though pointers are a kind of iterator).

---

#### Standardese

The rules in the standard relating to this capability [are given in terms of arrays](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2), but [a note reminds us](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#footnote-80) that a single object is considered to be an element of a single-element array for these purposes, citing the following passage which describes the meaning of your pointer:

> [`[basic.compound/3]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.sentence-9): *[..]* A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object46 or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively. *[..]* **For purposes of pointer arithmetic** ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), **a pointer past the end of the last element of an array `x` of *n* elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element *n* of `x` and an object of type `T` that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`.**  *[..]*

So, yes, you can safely "get" the one-past-the-end pointer per these rules. Unfortunately, you can't do much with it afterwards, since the pointer addition and subtraction rules are defined thus:

> [`[expr.add/4]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4): When an expression `J` that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression `P` of pointer type, the result has the type of `P`.
>
> - If `P` evaluates to a null pointer value and `J` evaluates to `0`, the result is a null pointer value.
> - Otherwise, **if `P` points to an array element *i* of an array object `x` with *n* elements** ([dcl.array]),80 the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i+j* of `x` if *0≤i+j≤n* and the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i−j* of `x` if *0≤i−j≤n*.
> - **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

…and `&x+1` is not an element of even the made-up array presented by the object `x`.

If it said *"if `P` points to a (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i* of an array object `x` with *n* elements"* then you'd be fine, because this would expand the behaviour given in the second bullet point to cover the one-past-the-end pointer (which is a "hypothetical array element of `x`" per the first quote). But it doesn't, so we fall through to the third bullet point, leaving your program with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225647/discussion-on-answer-by-asteroids-with-wings-is-incrementing-decrementing-or-add).